# UIImageView.hidden property not functioning?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, properties

PanelImage is Global allocED and initiated in a method called from ViewDidLoad

```
PanelImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"panel.png"];
[self.view addsubView:PanelImage];
```

My image comes up properly but 
    when i try to hide it using

> PanelImage.hidden = YES;

it Doesn't hide
 i test the property using

> if(PanelImage.hidden) but i doesnt pass

i also printed it

```
NSLog(@"panel is hidden %d",PanelImage.hidden);
```

it outputs "Panel is hidden 0" even after setting it by

> PanelImage.hidden = 1;

please help,atleast tell me some technique to debug it.
there are lots of methods which are using PanelImage.hidden,it used to work before 2days.now only point where PanelImage.hidden works is the custom initialization function(called from ViewDidLoad)
also this is piece of a very big code.

after lots of debugging i came to a point where PanelImage.hidden goes inoperable

```
    PanelImage.hidden = YES;//works till here here
    [self GetSymbolAttr];//wont work after this function is called
```

definition of GetSymbolAttr

```
   -(void)GetSymbolAttr
 {

int tmp = 0;
NSArray* PosAndSizeArrForCurrSlot = [[PosAndSizeArr objectAtIndex:SlotId] componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" "]];
for(NSString* values in PosAndSizeArrForCurrSlot)
    PositionAndSize[tmp++]  = [values intValue];

 }
```

as you can see nothing is happening in GetSymbolAttr which will make Pattern.hidden go inoperatble

Answer (score 2):

if `PanelImage.hidden = YES;` is now working than you can do its alpha.set to zero . `PanelImage.alpha = 0 ;`

Comment: didnt work ,what else could be the problem ?is there something internal of UIImageView which i need to know!

Comment: first check your IBoutlet connection link .normally your code is not wrong. its working in my case . please make sure your link is connected properly

Comment: i m not using IBOutlet at all !

Comment: if you want to hide on a perticular click event than also try thisUIImageView *PanelImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImageNamed:@""];

Comment: PanelImage is global,the image is never gonna change! i set it up just once! in ViewDidLoad

Comment: But in your code you have another local variable with same name

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    UIImageView *PanelImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage ...]];
    [self.view addsubView:PanelImage];
```

I didn't find `initWithImageNamed` method with `UIImageView` !

Comment: i didnt copy the code here properly my mistake,i edited the question

Comment: can you suggest me some diffrent method to debug as in my code there are lots of methods which are using PanelImage.hidden,it used to work before 2days.now only point where PanelImage.hidden works is the custom initialization function(called from ViewDidLoad)

Comment: the code works fine at my side... try : [PanelImage setHidden:YES];

Comment: it used to work for me too but something has gone wrong after a point no operation on PatternImage works it just stays visible throughtout the app!

Comment: clean your build and then try again

Comment: is there any condition,when UIImageView.hidden or UIImageView.alpha might be nonfunctional?

Comment: [PanelImage setHidden:YES]; doesn't work either.i guess problem is something diffrent because if i print PanelImage.hidden after [PanelImage setHidden:YES]; or PanelIamge.hidden = YES; it stays 0.
i also cleaned it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3238/discussion-between-yadnesh-and-maulik)

Answer (score 0):

Do you set PanelImage.hidden = YES in the same metod, where you're doing UIImageView *PanelImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImageNamed:@"Panel.png"];? Or haven't you class field with the same name PanelImage?

Comment: as i said i m using it in lots of methods,but yes its also in the same method where i init the PanelImage! does it make diffrence?

Comment: delete UIImageView * from your code, you create new local variable that has no relation to the global

Comment: nice suggesion,
but i dont think so because custom initialization function does this 
PanelImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Panel.png"]];
and not
UIImageView *PanelImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Panel.png"]];

Comment: Seems I mixed up the code with some of the comments, it seemed to me that UIImageView * was there